# Show that the triangle with vertices's P (4; 3; 6); Q(-2; 0; 8) and R(1; 5; 0) is a right angled triangle and find its area

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Show that the triangle with vertices P (4; 3; 6); Q(2; 0; 8) and R(1; 5; 0) is a right angled
triangle and find its area
this whre im stuck:i tried to find the dot product of QP and QR i found (6,3,-2) and (3,5,-8) but their dot product is not giving me zero:

Comment: A right triangle has 3 angles, only one of which is right. If you've found one non-right angle, check a different angle.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$PR=\sqrt{9+4+36}=7$$
$$PQ=\sqrt{36+9+4}=7$$
$$RQ=\sqrt{1+25+64}=\sqrt{98}$$
so $$PQ^2+RQ^2=49+49=98$$

Comment: I'm not a doc in Medizin!

Comment: Could you solve your Problem now?

Comment: im using the Pythagoras theorem to find which sides are orthogonal ...having problem finding one..

Comment: Are you sure that your coordinates have no typos?

Comment: Check they again,please!

Comment: found the typo its (-2,0,8) o the second coordinate

Comment: OK, after Pythagoras apply Heron/Brahmagupta using lengths of three sides.

Comment: owkae thanx man ...

Comment: No Heron please, $$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 49$$

Comment: @johnDoe Edit your question to correct that typo so that you don’t waste other peoples’ time!